# how to print embedded tomcat console to a external file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have been trying to make complete embedded tomcat console to print in a external log file but not working for me as log4j is printing only loggers info, I want even syso,exception,log everything in that file, please help me on this.

Comment: All of what you are asking about has to do with configuring `log4j` the way you want.  You can add a RollingFileAppender to write to a file, and you can enable logging of the more detailed log levels.  You say it is "printing only loggers info", but it would be really unusual for it to be showing INFO entries but not WARN and ERROR.  If you're really getting INFO entries, something's wacky. - have you played at all with your log4j configuration?  Do you know how to do that...where the config file is?

Comment: yes i have added log4j inside resources and as well as added dependencies in pom.xml as well

Comment: i need to use swallowOutput="true" but how to use in spring boot's yml file